# Ruby -v showing older version when installing with Rbenv 2.2.3

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I did

```
rbenv install 2.2.3
Rbenv Rehash
rbenv Global 2.2.3
```

however when I check the ruby -v it says

```
ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [universal.x86_64-darwin14]
```

And if I try rbenv install again, it says it already exists on

```
Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3
```

Comment: Make sure your rbenv config comes first in your path.

Comment: Also a which ruby Will show which one is being run.

Comment: It says user/bin/ruby

Comment: How do I make rbenv config come first in my path?

Answer (score 1):

For now, adding the following to your shell initialization file (`~/.bash_profile` for bash users) will fix your problem.

```
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

Read about what this does [here](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#how-rbenv-hooks-into-your-shell). I recommend reading the official documentation. Bit long, but informative and interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it by using rvm to install ruby and doing

```
rvm default ruby
```